# Raster manipulation in ArcGIS - Flood Mapping with HAND

Tags: arcgis-desktop, flood, hand

I am trying to create flood maps using the height above nearest drainage (HAND) method using data from the continental flood inundation mapping (CFIM) project. I have the following data:

A raster map of subcatchments

[image: raster map of subcatchments]

A map of HAND elevations

[image: map of HAND elevations]

A table of flow/water height for each catchment
[image: table of flow/water height for each catchment]

I will calculate a flow for each catchment, then using the table, I need to apply a unique water height to
each subcatchment. I am new to ArcGIS and I am looking for general guidance for how to do this. I need to break up the map of HAND elevations into the subcatchments shown, then apply a unique elevation mask to each layer.

How should I do this?

I can code in Python but I'm not sure what functions I need to use.

Comment: A quick update! I used the Raster to Polygon tool to turn the catchments into polygon shapes. Then I used Split Raster to break up the HAND map into individual catchments

Comment: Are you trying to do this in ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  Does your comment mean that you are no longer stuck on what you asked in your question?  If not, or if you are now stuck somewhere else, then please [edit] your question to make clear what it is that you are currently stuck.